# Why is a dash in my font awesome icon of 'envelope'(Screenshot below)

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

The envelope icon having that weird dash beside it

[image]

I also tried adding a similar icon from font-awesome 4, But still not good.

The code I used for that is below -

```html
<i class="far fa-envelope" class="inbox"></i>
```

And, I also haven't made any changes to it in CSS.

Comment: Are you sure it is far instead of fa fa-envelope?

Comment: try text-decoration:none;

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @noobprogrammer Yes, far means Font-Awesome Regular(size).

Comment: @TemaniAfif It worked, I can't believe, it is such a silly mistake not considered. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh, I started using Stack overflow today, so I am a newbie here, didn't knew that, Thanks!

Comment: You may need to use 'className' instead of 'class'.

Answer (score 1):

If your fontawesome Icon is wrapped in an anchor tag () the style for the anchor would need its text-decoration set to none to remove the dash.

**Example:**

```
<a href="https://XXXXX" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x" style="color: #3b5998;"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `text-decoration: none;` to your class.

It would look like this:

```
.inbox { 
         text-decoration: none; 
       }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For starters you have the “class” attribute declared twice. As for the hyphen, perhaps you have this icon nested in strike-through HTML tags or a CSS attribute declaring this. I can’t say for sure without seeing the full CSS for where the icon is displayed.

Comment: Can't we add multiple classes to an element?

Comment: You need to put the class items in the same class attribute like you did for "far fa-envelope". The class="inbox" will be ignored by most browsers because "class" has already been declared. You should use, class="far fa-envelope inbox" instead.

Comment: So the thing that all tutors say "we can add multiple classes to an element" was meant by this, didn't knew this before, Thanks!